# Update statement updates all records in the table and not the ones related to the condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this following table called STG_Params :

```
Schema Table           DataBase Flag_Full
dbo    Users           LocalDB  1
dbo    bankInformation LocalDB  0
dbo    Language        LocalDB  0
dbo    Employee        LocalDB  1
dbo    WorkPermit      LocalDB  1
dbo    Roles           LocalDB  1
dbo    School          LocalDB  1
dbo    Nationality     LocalDB  1
dbo    Degree          LocalDB  1
```

I want to update records having TableName like below and set their Flag_Full to 0 :

```
UPDATE STG_Param SET Flag_Full = 0 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT m.* from STG_Param m where m.[Table] in ('Users','Employee','Roles',WorkPermit')
```

When I execute the query it updates all the records with Flag_Full=1 including the table names not mentioned in the where condition.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is always evaluating to `true` since you're just checking whether at least one of the four table names exists. Which is always the case, so every single row is part of the data to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an alias to the table you are updating and use the where condition directly. You can also use joins before the WHERE clause if you need to get the list of tables based on a condition in another table.

```
UPDATE STG 
SET STG.Flag_Full = 0 
FROM STG_Param STG
WHERE STG.[Table] IN ('Users','Employee','Roles','WorkPermit')
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 queries here that make up your full statement. The first is `UPDATE STG_Param SET Flag_Full = 0`, and this will update a row provided that the following sub-query (which is **not** correlated) returns at least one row: `SELECT m.* from STG_Param m where m.[Table] in ('Users','Employee','Roles',WorkPermit')`.

This means that if at least one row in the table `STG_Param` has the value `'Users'`,`'Employee'`,`'Roles'` or `'WorkPermit'` for the column `Table`, then **all** rows in the table `STG_Param` will be updated, as the `EXISTS` will return *TRUE*.

What you need here is just a simple `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE STG_Param 
SET Flag_Full = 0 
WHERE [Table] IN ('Users','Employee','Roles',WorkPermit');
```